# How to map string Api Response?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapping, fetch-api

```
{
    "response_code": "1",
    "message": "Workout Found",
    "workout": {
        "id": "1",
        "goalid": "3",
        "levelid": "1",
        "workname": "At - Home  Cardio for  Fat Loss",
        "dow": "4",
        "image": "https://sparksapps.in/gym/uploads/6218a2c119f28.jpg",
        "goal_name": "Transform",
        "level_name": "Beginner",
        "fav_status": "1"
    },
    "status": "success"
}

//code
     {data?.map((element, i) => {  //data =>response setData(resp.workout)
        return (
          <div className="col-md-4" key={i}>
            <div
              className="card card-cascade wider"
              style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "start" }}
            >
              <div className="view view-cascade overlay">
                <img className="card-img-top" src={element.image} alt="Card image cap"/>
                <a href="#!">
                  <div className="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body card-body-cascade text-center pb-0">
                <h5 className="card-title">id:{element.id}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">goalid:{element.goalid}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">levelid:{element.levelid}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">workname:{element.workname}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">dow:{element.dow}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">goal_name:{element.goal_name}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">level_name:{element.level_name}</h5>
                <h5 className="card-title">fav_status:{element.fav_status}</h5>
               
                <div className="card-footer text-muted text-center mt-4">
                  2 days ago
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

react mapping not working i've tried using Object.entries(resp.workout) it returns the no. of values notthe Actual Data from the Api ! Response is Completly Working but what mistake am i making in the creation of map method !! help me Out Thank You!!!

Comment: Hi @Vasim, welcome to Stack overflow, please could you be more specific in your question? Show all the content of API, and also show the code component separately. If needed you can make a sandbox example with several tools on the internet, for example, code sandbox.

Comment: can you tell what error are you getting and what is the complete component you are trying to render

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **resp.workout** type to `Array`, if you want to use `MAP method`.

```
{
...
"workout": [
  {
   "id": "1",
   "goalid": "3",
   "levelid": "1",
   "workname": "At - Home  Cardio for  Fat Loss",
   "dow": "4",
   "image": "https://sparksapps.in/gym/uploads/6218a2c119f28.jpg",
   "goal_name": "Transform",
   "level_name": "Beginner",
   "fav_status": "1"
  }
 ],
}
```

Or you can set `Initial value` of state is `Empty Array` and then use `useEffect` to `setData`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  // Call API
  ...
  setData((prevState) => [...prevState, response.workout]);
  // setData([...data, response.workout]);
  // setData([response.workout])
}, [])
```

Comment: thank you for replying sir but i am already using useEfect to fetch and set Data , and i can't   replace resp.workout type to Array bcus its from live project though i'm converting it to react

Comment: So use `second idea` : set `Initial state` is `empty array` and then use `useEffect + setState`   @VasimShaikh

Comment: thankyou sir but  i tried this too ,    const [data,setData]=useState([]);     useEffect(()={setData(data.push(resp.workout))  <- both -> {setData(resp.workout)}
}        {data?.map((element, i) => {return(<h4>{emement.dow}</h4>)}..........its Showing map is not a function error

Comment: thank you so Much SIr @Anh Le Hoang i solved this with your help, and my concept of initial state is cleared ......Thank you sir Once Again ......................................Solution : setData([resp.workout])

Comment: You can use `setState`  by pass `callback function` like as`my edited answer` or to easy understand,  you can use `setState(resp.workout)` in `useEffect` as you did @VasimShaikh

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [data, setData] = useState();  // state

  useEffect(() => { *emphasized text*
    (async () => {
          setData([resp.workout]);  `setState inside Array`
        });
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

- List item
  put the Initial state is empty array inside your `SetState` or You can directly set your object value within your `SetState`